# DashPlotly обновление графика "в режиме реального времени"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, dash

Всех приветствую. В начальном этапе построения дашборда столкнулся с одним нюансом: все данные хранятся в бд. Запись в бд идет. В дашборд данные идут через pandas. При запуске дашборда неимеются никаких проблем.

сам код:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
import numpy as np
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html



timezone = pytz.timezone("Etc/UTC")
utc_from = datetime(2021, 3, 23, tzinfo=timezone)
#Создает новый файл , если он есть то просто подключается
base = sqlite3.connect('base_eurousd.db')
#Класс для создания, чтения, изменения таблиц
cur = base.cursor()
# получение данных
read_db = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM data_eurusd').fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(read_db)
#d = pd.read_sql("select * from data", db_conn)
print(df)


df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0], unit='ms')
df[3] = np.where(df[1].diff().lt(0)|df[2].diff().lt(0), df[3]*-1, df[3])

#ДАШБОРД
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='HELLO DASH'),
    html.H2(children='My first dash'),

    html.Div(children='''Dash : A web application framework for Python'''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x':df[0], 'y':df[1],  'name': 'BID', 'marker': {'color': 'red'}},
                {'x':df[0], 'y':df[2],  'name': 'ASK', 'marker': {'color': 'blue'}},
            ],
            'layout' : {
                'title': 'ПРОБНЫЙ ТЕСТ ВИЗУАЛИЗАЦИИ'
            }
        }
    )
])
if __name__ == '__main__' :
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

вывод df :

```
                   0        1        2  3
0      1623066946305  1.21623  1.21625  2
1      1623066946432  1.21622  1.21625  2
2      1623066947746  1.21621  1.21624  6
3      1623066949244  1.21621  1.21623  4
4      1623066949587  1.21621  1.21624  4
...              ...      ...      ... ..
85715  1623171716674  1.21840  1.21842  2
85716  1623171716808  1.21841  1.21843  6
85717  1623171717070  1.21841  1.21842  4
85718  1623171717419  1.21839  1.21841  6
85719  1623171717538  1.21838  1.21840  6
```

Нюанс: каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы данные подгружались "в режиме онлайн"? На данный момент только перезапуск файла может с этим помочь ... Буду рад хоть небольшим подсказкам в этом направлении)

Comment: А что мешает обернуть считывание из базы и отрисовку дашборда в функцию, и вызывать ее по циклу с таймаутом?

Comment: мешает объем информации, на сколько я понимаю, как только датафрейм перейдет границу в 200к строк, будет очень долго грузится. По факту все равно что перезапуск всего дашборда.. А вот подгрузка данных совсем то что нужно..

Comment: Если вы собираетесь аккумулировать данные, то все равно достигните некоторого предела информации. Если же вам нужны данные за какой-то конечный промежуток времени, то и забирайте из бд какой-то конечный обеъм последних данных и перезаписывайте датафрейм.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это конечно наспех собранная версия дашборда, но хоть как-то нужный функционал дает!

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import sqlite3
import pytz
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

app = dash.Dash(__name__)



points = 0
def test():
    global points
    points += 1

def get_value(n_intervals):
    timezone = pytz.timezone("Etc/UTC")
    utc_from = datetime(2021, 3, 23, tzinfo=timezone)
    base = sqlite3.connect('base_eurousd.db')
    cur = base.cursor()
    read_db = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM data_eurusd').fetchall()
    df = pd.DataFrame(read_db)
    # d = pd.read_sql("select * from data", db_conn)


    df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0], unit='ms')
    df[3] = np.where(df[1].diff().lt(0) | df[2].diff().lt(0), df[3] * -1, df[3])
    #print(df)
    return df


def serve_layout():
    return html.Div(
        children=[
            html.H4(children='Доска'),
            html.Div(id='my-id', children='''EURUSD'''),
            dcc.Graph(id='example-graph', animate=True, responsive=True),
            dcc.Interval(
                id='interval-component',
                interval=3 * 1000,
                n_intervals=0,
            ),
        ],
    )

app.layout = serve_layout

@app.callback(
    Output('example-graph','figure'),
    [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])
def update_graph(n_intervals):
    df = get_value(n_intervals)
    test()
    return  \
        {
            'data': [
                {'x': df[0], 'y': df[1], 'type': 'line', 'name': 'BID'},
                {'x': df[0], 'y': df[2], 'type': 'line', 'name': 'ASK'},
            ],
            'layout': go.Layout(xaxis=dict(range=[min(df[0]),max(df[0])]),yaxis=dict(range=[min(df[1]),max(df[2])]),)
        }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

хочу отметить одно, через час - полтора из-за большого кол-ва данных идет нагрузка на процессор. Пользуйтесь)